# Coffeescript + Backbone "Each" callback function

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have the following in my coffeescript/backbone app. The problem is it's running console.log BEFORE the "each" function is complete (in other words, before it's done doing create() for each collection).  What I would like to know is if there is some type of success callback I can use that I'm not aware of in order to run console.log once the creates are complete. Thanks in advance!

```
wishlist.each (model) ->
  id = model.get('id')
  lineitems.create({product_id: id})
console.log "do this when finished!"
```

Comment: I don't see any AJAX.  Does `each()` magically do some lazy loading under the covers or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused.  The `each` function on `Backbone.Collection`s is not asynchronous and it doesn't trigger any AJAX calls.  The `each` function actually comes from Underscore which isn't concerned with async functionality.

The asynchronous AJAX call that fetches the data is called `fetch` and it does have a success/error callback:

```
wishlist.fetch
  success: -> console.log "success"
  error: -> console.log "error"
```

**EDIT**

OK, so you want `console.log` to execute after ALL creations have completed.  First of all, what I said about `fetch` is true of create.  You can add `success` and `error` callbacks.

```
lineitems.create {product_id: id}, 
    {success: @create_success, error: @create_error}
```

I would consider incrementing a count for every `create` and decrementing the count on every `success` and `error` callbacks.  When you have finished creating AND your count reaches 0, you have processed all the creations and you can call it back.

Comment: @muistooshort ???  What are you suggesting?  He is telling us that the console.log happens before the each function has completed, which is a synchronous function.  This doesn't make sense.  Yes, `Collection.create` is asynchronous but I am not sure what you are suggesting with your "Ahem".

Comment: No, he's saying that `console.log` executes before all of the `create` calls have fully completed and `create` **is** asynchronous due to the underlying AJAX it does.

Comment: Aaaah... that was not clear to me at all.  Let me update my response, then.